# Enviar mails en Laravel, en producción

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto laravel en el cuál necesito mandar emails. En local funciona perfecto pero cuando lo subo a un hosting en la web deja de funcionar. ¿Es que debo cambiar algo para pasarlo a producción?

Controller:

```
    class merluzaController extends Controller
{
    public function mail(request $request){
        $datos=[
            "nombre"=>$request->nombre,
            "apellido"=>$request->apellido,
            "correo"=>$request->correoE,
            "numeroT"=>$request->numeroT,
            "mensaje"=>$request->mensaje,
        ];
        Mail::send('emails.mails', $datos, function ($message) {
            $message->to("ltomicb@gmail.com", "Lucas")->subject('Página de MerluzaDePincho');

        });
        Session::flash('mensaje_enviado','Mensaje enviado correctamente.');
        return redirect('/contacto');
    }
}
```

ENV:

```
 MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandbox8f7345b6f0f14762871d8489a6a672c9.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=****************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=merluzadepincho@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Merluza de Pincho"
```

Al parecer no llega al redirect en el metodo mail, porqué se detiene en este link:
https://merluzadepincho.000webhostapp.com/mail?nombre=Lucas&apellido=asd&correoE=asd&numeroT=asd&mensaje=mensaje+de+prasdueba&enviar=Enviar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes verificar que los puertos en el servidor estén disponibles, que tengas los permisos correspondientes y/o agregar las reglas del firewall para que permita la salida del SMTP.

Comment: Por defecto, el protocolo SMTP trabaja con 3 puertos:

Port 25 - Este es el predeterminado para SMTP no cifrado.
Port 2525 - Este puerto está abierto en todos los servidores de SiteGround por si el puerto 25 este bloqueado por parte de tu proveedor de Internet y quieres enviar correo no cifrado por SMTP.
Port 465 - Este es el puerto que debes usar si quieres conectarte usando SMTP de forma segura (cifrada).

Comment: Hola, y donde puedo verificar todo eso? @floyd70s

Comment: donde estas hosteando la app? AWS, GC, AZURE o es un host de terceros por ejemplo hostingABC????

Comment: Es un host de terceros si no me equivoco, WebHost000. Por lo que dicen los detalles del servidor, el puerto el el 21

Comment: vi que lo tienes en https://www.000webhost.com.

Comment: Así es, pero cómo puedo usar eso para que los emails se manden correctamente al igual que en local?

Comment: prueba con el puerto 25

Comment: Lo cambio desde el env?

Comment: si:   MAIL_PORT=21

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, pero active el APP_DEBUG y me reconoce el error. "Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Mail' not found" ¿Que puede ser?

Comment: Mailgun debe de darte las variables de entorno para poder enviar emails, este ultimo error que muestra es porque el facade o la clase Mail no esta importada al principio del controlador

Comment: Si lo está, de lo contrario no funcionaría en local. No sé porque me muestra este error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, ya pude entender mi error. Cuando importaba la clase en vez de "Facades" tenía escrito "facades". Es raro que en local no me de errores pero sí en producción. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En local no son tan estricto con las mayusculas como lo son en produccion